# sqlldr LRM-00112: multiple values not allowed for parameter 'control'

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a shell script with this code:

```
sqlldr $ws_usr_eva/$ws_pass_eva@$ws_esq_eva CONTROL=/$HOME/controlfiles/CONTROL_FILE.CTL LOG=/$HOME/batch/log/LOG_FILE.$fecfile.log DATA=/$HOME/batch/input/INPUT_FILE_$fecfile.txt > /$HOME/batch/log/result_loader_eva.ora
```

The variables $ws_usr_eva, $ws_pass_eva and $ws_esq_eva are filled before I execute the sqlldr. I already check the content and its ok.

So when I run the script, it show me: LRM-00112: multiple values not allowed for parameter 'control'

I tried to run the script without the variables, and it works fine:

```
sqlldr user/pwd@schema CONTROL=/$HOME/controlfiles/CONTROL_FILE.CTL LOG=/$HOME/batch/log/LOG_FILE.$fecfile.log DATA=/$HOME/batch/input/INPUT_FILE_$fecfile.txt > /$HOME/batch/log/result_loader_eva.ora
```

I have to use variables in the sqlldr, because it reads them from a configuration file.

I also try with sqlldr userid=$ws_usr_eva/$ws_pass_eva@$ws_esq_eva ... but it didn't work.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I realize that the concatenation of the variables is replacing the characters, something like this:  ABCDEFG/HIJK@KLM returns KLMKEFG.   How can i concatenate the variables in the correct way?

Answer (score 3):

Incase it helps anybody, you need to enclose your paths (data, control, log) in single qoutes. Double qoutes will not work (although sqlldr will not complain, but rather simply ignore the double qoutes).

Answer (score 1):

In your shell, try to escape your variables::

```
sqlldr "${ws_usr_eva}/${ws_pass_eva}@${ws_esq_eva}" "CONTROL=${HOME}/controlfiles/CONTROL_FILE.CTL" "LOG=${HOME}/batch/log/LOG_FILE.${fecfile}.log" "DATA=${HOME}/batch/input/INPUT_FILE_${fecfile}.txt" > "${HOME}/batch/log/result_loader_eva.ora"
```